# Manually input 3-way contingency in ftable() format in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a 3-way/3-dimensional contingency table in R in the `ftable()` format for a test. Unfortunately all the examples I've seen on how to create this derives data from a large dataset where the counts are not already done. I already have a summary of the counts. Would it be possible to **manually** enter my data in R?

For example, my usual way of creating a two-dimensional contingency, e.g. 2x3 is to manually input a matrix, e.g. `matrix(c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60), nrow=3, ncol=2)`

I'd like to find a similar way to input data for the 3-dimensional table.

I have three variables--Race, Build, Diet. My data looks something like this:

```
MEDITERRANEAN DIET
       Race
       White   Black
Slim   35      55
Normal 75      65
Obese  100     80

AMERICAN DIET
       Race
       White   Black
Slim   12      10
Normal 50      70
Obese  255     157
```

And example of the output I'm looking for in `ftable()` format is:

```
       DIET            American      Mediterranean
RACE        BUILD
White       Slim       12            35
            Normal     50            75
            Obese      255           100
Black       Slim       10            55
            Normal     70            65
            Obese      157           80
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dim` to set the dimensions of the matrix after inputting the data as a vector and then `aperm` to rearrange the dimensions.

```
mat <- c(12,50,255,10,70,157, 35, 75, 100, 55, 65, 80)
dim(mat) <- c(3,2,2)
dimnames(mat) <- list(Build=c("Slim","Normal","Obese"),   # 1st dimension (rows)
                      Race=c("White","Black"),            # 2nd dimension (columns)
                      Diet=c("American","Mediterranean")) # 3rd dimension (strata)

mat
, , Diet = American

        Race
 Build   White Black
  Slim      12    10
  Normal    50    70
  Obese    255   157

, , Diet = Mediterranean

        Race
 Build    White Black
  Slim      35    55
  Normal    75    65
  Obese    100    80
```

The `ftable` does what you want, but the output is not in the desired orientation because of the dimension issue.

```
ftable(mat)
```

So you can use `aperm` to rearrange the dimensions, switch the rows and columns:

```
mat2 <- aperm(mat, c(2,1,3))

ftable(mat2)
             Diet American Mediterranean
Race  Build                            
White Slim              12            35
      Normal            50            75
      Obese            255           100
Black Slim              10            55
      Normal            70            65
      Obese            157            80
```

Of course, you could always enter the data in the correct sequence first, then the `aperm` command is unnecessary.